# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to save the gridview data into the database. To decide if it should be an Insert or update, i need to find out if the `Order_SelectionID` exists. Foreach Gridview row, i am trying to use the statement like the following in C# using Asp.Net.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdFavoriteMerchant.Rows)
    {
        if (grdFavoriteMerchant.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["Order_SelectionID"].ToString() != "")
        {
```

If `Order_SelectionID` exists and not a `NUll` or zero, i will have to "Insert", else an "Update".

This statement gives me an exception

> "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types."

everytime when i am supposed to use an Insert. How can i correct it?

Comment: FYI OP, you are not checking if `Order_SelectionID` is `null` or `zero` in your code above.  You are checking to see if it is an empty string; which is different than the two examples you noted above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not compare directly to `DBNull.Value`?

```
if(grdFavoriteMerchant.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["Order_SelectionID"]
                                     ==  DBNull.Value)
```

Comment: I was not clear if i can compare like that. Something new to learn! Thank you!!